# unable to call wcf post from jquery

Tags: jquery, json, wcf, post, wcf-rest

I get a error like this when I'm trying to post to wcf service method from jquery.
"Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied".  I tried it from fiddler and it works, unable to figure out. Had been trying it for almost a day but couldn't nail down. Any help would be greatly appreciated my friends. Thanks in advance

Here is my jquery code

```
function testUlsService()
{
    debugger;
    var myurl = "http://azcrmcritdevwb1.red.com:84/ULSService.svc/ulsrest/PostToUls";


    var result;
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",                                                                                //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
        url: myurl,   //Location of the service
        data: JSON.stringify({ "GameID" : "Created from emulator" }),                    //Data sent to server
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                                               //content type sent to server
        dataType: "json",                                                                             //Expected data format from server
        processdata: true,                                                                           //True or False
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (msg) { result = msg; },
        error: ServiceFailed
    });

    return result;

}
```

Here is my wcf config

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="servicebehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>

    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
  <behavior name="restbehavior">
    <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />        
  </behavior>

 </endpointBehaviors>    
</behaviors>

<services>  
   <service name="Microsoft.IT.CCRM.CRTISIT.ULSWebService.ULSService" behaviorConfiguration="servicebehavior">

    <endpoint name="soapendpoint" contract="Microsoft.IT.CCRM.CRTISIT.ULSWebService.IUlSService"
              binding="basicHttpBinding" address="soap"  />

    <endpoint name="restendpoint"
              contract="Microsoft.IT.CCRM.CRTISIT.ULSWebService.IUlSService"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              address="ulsrest"
              behaviorConfiguration="restbehavior"

      />
     <endpoint name="mexendpoint" address="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding"/>
  </service>
</services>  

<protocolMapping>
    <!--<add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="https" />-->      
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"  />
```

Comment: Try capturing the raw request using Fiddler and compare with the request that works from fiddler